# How can I automatically preform operations when a vim *window* is resized?

Tags: vim-windows, autocmd, formatting

I'm setting up NeoFormat/ALEfix-style code reformatting, and I'd really like to have it automatically and fluidly reformat the code as the window is resized. This is possible for whole-viewport vim-windows with the `VimResized` autocmd; but I see no corresponding `WinResized` autocmd.

Is there an efficient way to add some buffer-local behaviour (i.e. as mentioned above, running code through a width-aware reformatter) to be preformed every time a Vim *window* is resized (i.e. `⌃w` `=`, `:vertical resize 100`, et. al)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there's no autocommand for this (although it would be very useful).

A possible way to do this is to poll vim every `CursorHold` event, and check to see if the window size has changed; the `winwidth()` and `winheight()` functions can give the current height of a window. By default `CursorHold` is triggered after 4 seconds of vim receiving no input, but that can be reduced by changing the `'updatetime'` option. Not exactly fluid but better than nothing.

(Everything marked in code blocks can be looked up in vim's help by passing it exactly as written to `:h`)